# Link 2 Data Validation Cells

Tags: excel, vba, validation

I am trying to link 2 cells that have data validation lists in them so that when 1 of the cells (ex. cell A2) is filled with the SKU in from a selection in the dropdown list, cell B2 will be filled with the SKU description and vice versa.

See the pictures below with that I have so far. I have named the columns:

Column A = a_val

Column B = b_val

SKU column with values = vrac

SKU description column with values = vrac_description

Table with SKUs and SKU descriptions = description

See the attached pictures for what I currently have.

1 sheet is the empty fields, I have data validation lists on columns A and B since I want to be able to have the option to select either from column A or column B but would like either one to auto-populate when I've selected an item from the list in the opposite cell

Thank you!

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

   If Not Intersect(Target, Range("a_val")) Is Nothing Then
        With Application.WorksheetFunction
            UI False
                Range("b_val").Value = .Index(Range("vrac_description").Value, .Match(Range("a_val").Value, Range("description").Value, 0))
            UI True
        End With

    ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, [b_val]) Is Nothing Then
        With Application.WorksheetFunction
            UI False
                [a_val].Value = .Index([vrac], .Match([b_val], [vrac_description], 0))
            UI True
        End With
    End If

End Sub

Public Sub UI(t As Boolean)

    Application.EnableEvents = t
    Application.ScreenUpdating = t

End Sub
```

[Current Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGkPG.png)

[Main Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jl4kS.png)

[Data Validation Lookup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YDIhm.png)

[EDIT} New code attempt:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

   If Not Intersect(Target, a_val) Is Nothing Then
    With Application.WorksheetFunction
        UI False
           'b_val = .VLookup(Target, Description, 1, 0)
           Range(Target.Column + 1).Value = .Index(vrac_description, .Match(Target.Value, vrac, 0))
        UI True
    End With

ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, b_val) Is Nothing Then
    With Application.WorksheetFunction
        UI False
            'Range(Target.Column - 1).Value = .VLookup(Target.Value, Description, 1, 0)
            Range(Target.Column - 1).Value = .Index(vrac, .Match(Target.Value, vrac_description, 0))
        UI True
    End With
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of your code. Instead, paste the actual code into your question so that people can copy/paste it if they want to.

Comment: Which sheet is the description table on ?

Comment: @braX - I've added the code to my question, thanks for that.

Comment: @CDP1802 - the description table is on a sheet named Data_Validation

Answer (score 0):

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Msgbox "Target=" & Target.Address
    On Error GoTo errorexit
    Dim r, i As Long, cell As Range
    i = Target.Column
    If i > 2 Or Target.Value = "" Then Exit Sub
    
    Set cell = Target.Offset(, 3 - i * 2)
    With Sheets("Data_Validation").ListObjects("description").DataBodyRange
        r = Application.Match(Target.Value, .Columns(i), 0)
        If Not IsError(r) Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            cell = .Cells(r, 3 - i).Value
        Else
            MsgBox Target.Value & " not found in column " & i
        End If
    End With
errorexit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Your code corrected

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   
    On Error GoTo exiterror
    
    Dim a_val As Range, b_val As Range
    Dim vrac As Range, vrac_description As Range
   
    ' define ranges
    With ThisWorkbook
        Set a_val = .Names("a_val").RefersToRange
        Set b_val = .Names("b_val").RefersToRange
        Set vrac = .Names("vrac").RefersToRange
        Set vrac_description = .Names("vrac_description").RefersToRange
    End With
    
    If Not Intersect(Target, a_val) Is Nothing Then
        With Application.WorksheetFunction
            UI False
               Target.Offset(, 1).Value = .Index(vrac_description, .Match(Target.Value, vrac, 0))
            UI True
        End With

    ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, b_val) Is Nothing Then
        With Application.WorksheetFunction
            UI False
                Target.Offset(, -1).Value = .Index(vrac, .Match(Target.Value, vrac_description, 0))
            UI True
        End With
    End If
exiterror:
     Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I will be trying it tonight on my sheet and let you know how it turns out

Comment: Just tried this code and it still doesn't seem to work

Comment: @cpantoni Any error messages ?

Comment: not even, I don't see any indication of it running either which is weird, I tried something else similar to what I had demonstrated earlier and I feel like it's almost there I'm just trying to determine how to make it write in the cell, I'll add it in here

Comment: @cpantoni I have updated my code with some message boxes to check if event is being triggered. Is the code on the sheet with dropdown lists ?

Comment: sorry to the delay, Thank you for the edits and addition, no the code should be on a separate sheet. I would share the file with you if I can

Comment: For clarification, the sheet that the code should run on is named "Clean" the sheet where the dropdown list is pulling from the "Data_Validation"

Comment: @cpantoni so changes to cells on clean will trigger the worksheet_change event sub

Comment: Yes exactly that's the goal